# Lost on splay tree implementation

Tags: c++, linux, binary-search-tree, splay-tree

I'm having trouble debugging my code. I believe the error lies within the Insert function and Rotate but I cannot figure it out.. Please check my code

```
#pragma once
#include <cassert>
#include <stdexcept>

class splay_tree {
public:
    struct node 
    {
        node(int key, node* left, node* right, node* parent) :
            key(key), left(left), right(right), parent(parent) { }

        int key;
        node* left;
        node* right;
        node* parent;
    };

    ~splay_tree() 
    {
        clear();
    }

    node* root() const 
    {
        return rt;
    }

    int size() const 
    {
        return size(rt);
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return rt == nullptr;
    }

    static void rotate(node* c, node* p) 
    {
        assert(c != nullptr and p != nullptr);
        assert(c == p->left or c == p->right);
        assert(c->parent == p);

        node* g = p->parent;

        if(g != nullptr) 
        {
            if (g->left == p)
                g->left = c;
            else
                g->right = c;
        } 
        else
            c->parent = nullptr;

        p->parent = c;

        if(c == p->left) 
        {
            p->left = c->right;
            if(c->right != nullptr)
                c->right->parent = p;
            c->right = p;
        }
        else{
            p->right = c->left;
            if(c->left != nullptr)
                c->left->parent = p;
            c->left = p;
        }

        if(g != nullptr)
        {
            if(p == g->left)
                g->left = c;
            else
                g->right = c;
        }
    }

    static node* splay(node* n) 
    {
        assert(n != nullptr);

        while (n->parent != nullptr) 
        {
            node* p = n->parent;
            node* g = p->parent;

            if(p == nullptr){
                rotate(n,p);
            }
            else if((p == g->left and n == p->left) or (p == g->right and n == p->right)){
                rotate(p, g);
                rotate(n, p);
            }
            else if((p == g->left and n == p->right) or (p == g->right and n == p ->left)){
                rotate(n, p);
                rotate(n, g);
            }
        }
        return n;
    }

    node* find(int k)
    {
        node* n = rt;
        node* last = nullptr;

        while(n != nullptr)
        {
            last = n;

            if(k < n->key)
                n = n->left;
            else if(k > n->key)
                n = n->right;
            else{
                return splay(n);  
            }
        }

        return splay(last);  
    }

    node* insert(int k)
    {
        if(rt == nullptr){
            rt = new node(k, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
            return rt;
        }

        node* n = rt;
        node* last = nullptr;

        while(n != nullptr)
        {
            if(k == n->key)
            {
                delete n; 
                return rt;
            }
            last = n;
            if(k < n->key)
                n = n->left;
            else if(k > n->key)
                n = n->right;
        }

        if(k < last->key)
        {
            last->left = new node(k, nullptr, nullptr, last);
            return splay(last->left);
        }
        else{
            last->right = new node(k, nullptr, nullptr, last);
            return splay(last->right);
        }
    }

    node* remove(int k)
    {
    
        node* n = find(k);

        if(n != nullptr and n->key == k)
        {
            node* leftSubtree = n->left;
            node* rightSubtree = n->right;

            if(leftSubtree != nullptr){
                leftSubtree->parent = nullptr;
            }

            if(rightSubtree != nullptr){
                rightSubtree->parent = nullptr;
            }

            delete n;

            if(leftSubtree == nullptr){
                return rightSubtree;
            }
            else if(rightSubtree == nullptr){
                return leftSubtree;
            }
            else{
                node* maxNode = findMax(leftSubtree);
                maxNode->right = rightSubtree;
                rightSubtree->parent = maxNode;

                return maxNode;
            }
        }   
        splay(n);
        return rt;
    }

    void set_root(node* n) 
    {
        rt = n;
    }

    void clear() 
    {
        clear(rt);
        rt = nullptr;
    }

private:
    void clear(node* n) 
    {
        if (n != nullptr) {
            clear(n->left);
            clear(n->right);
            delete n;
        }
    }

    int size(node* n) const 
    {
        if (n == nullptr) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1 + size(n->left) + size(n->right);
    }

    node* findMax(node* n) const 
    {
        while (n->right != nullptr) {
            n = n->right;
        }
        return n;
    }

    node* rt = nullptr;
};
```

When I compile the test runner and run it this is my result:
---- Beginning tree tests ----
Testing rotation...Result of child-parent rotation (with subtrees) is incorrect:
Expected:

```
---- Beginning tree tests ----
Testing rotation...Result of child-parent rotation (with subtrees) is incorrect:
Expected:
--- Tree structure ---
 10
 ├─(null)
 └─  2 [p = 10]
    ├─  5 [p = 2]
    │  ├─  7 [p = 5]
    │  └─  3 [p = 5]
    └─  1 [p = 2]
Actual result:
--- Tree structure ---
 10
 ├─  2 [p = 5]
 │  ├─  5 [p = 2]
 │  │  ├─  7 [p = 5]
 │  │  └─  3 [p = 5]
 │  └─  1 [p = 2]
 └─CYCLE (2)
```

Please help me fix this problem.

[**Assignment Instructions**](https://fccsci.twicetwo.com/cs133/assignment4.html)

[**Test Runner**](https://fccsci.twicetwo.com/cs133/files/assign4_test.cpp)

Comment: Post the driver code also. Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ive attached a link to my assignment page and the test runner

Comment: I am not in the habit of following links to sites I do not know (and I am not the only one), nor do I want to do a full code review. So for us to help you we really need that minimal reproducible on this site as text (so when if needed I can copy the code into a local compiler)

Comment: You know what the input is (it is pictured in the test runner) so take pecil and paper, draw the tree, and then walk through your code while drawing what happens.

Comment: What state is your tree in after `delete n`?